# Rewrite any subdomain to https

Tags: apache, https

Currently I am running a little web server with apache on my LAMP system. I already created a https certificate for my domain. Now I would like to rewrite any subdomain and directory of subdomain to https without www. I already have a code in my .htaccess file and it rewrites the www version to non www and to https.

Here's the code in my .htaccess file (located in the root apache directory):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I already tried to just exchange the "www" with "(.*)" but I am not sure what "%1" and "$1" does because I found that code in the internet and they didn't explained it. I researched about regular expressions but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# domain starts with www (change yourdomain to your domain name)
# adding the domain name will ensure its not trying to capture a subdomain with www
# For example: ^www\.(.*)$ will redirect www.subdomain.domain.com to https.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(yourdomain) [NC]
# then redirect to HTTPS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# check if HTTPS is not being used
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# and because we already redirect www. we exclude it
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# and now we test to see if its a subdomain (change yourdomain to your domain name)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.]+\.yourdomain [NC]
# now we finally redirect it
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Once you confirm the subdomain redirection is working, you change `R=302` to `R=301`, the reason behind this, is to avoid your browser from caching the redirection until you can ensure its working.

If you do a mistake while using `R=301` the redirection will be cached and results may not be reliable in your browse until it clears up or you use a different browser.

`%1` is used when you're capturing something from the `RewriteCond` whereas `$1` is captured from the `RewriteRule`.

The number represent the captured value index, if you have anything resulting in multiple values, as you can see below with `$1` and `$2`.

[image: example]

When using `#` for comments ensure they are always in a new line and not at the end of the rule or it will fail to work.

Comment: Where do I need to locate the code of the redirection from a subdomain? Also in the root if the Apache folder?

Comment: @JohnMamor that will depend on how you have created those subdomains, if they are pointing to the same root folder your main domain is, then yes, you could put those rules in the same file. Otherwise you would have to create a new `.htaccess` within the location your subdomains reside in.

Comment: I didn't created the subdomains by myself. I bought a webmail for my domain and the it created the DNS records on my host. There is no location for the subdomains on my server.

Comment: You need either a wildcard setting in apache or their own subdomain configured otherwise apache will do a catch all to the default ip/domain of the server its configured at. So without further technical information about the server you have your domain at it would be hard to assist you, **at this point its no longer a .htaccess question but another question about how you assign those subdomains to your server, once the DNS are already configured.**

Comment: @JohnMamor you're welcome. If you post another question about configuring your domain on apache and information about how its hosted(if its your server, another company, if you have a control panel, etc), link it here and if I know I will help you out.